# How to refactor the method in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, refactoring

T want to divide a method into two, so that it can be used by two methods with different arguments.

What am I trying to do?

I have a method named `convert_point` that takes values `x` and `y` based on a click on a canvas and then converts that to `x`, `y` and `z` values as an array.

```
add_point_at = (x, y) => {
    this.props.convert_point([x, y]).then(converted_point => {
        let next;
        let some_var = this.state.some_var;
        if (some_var === undefined) {
            this.method1();
            next = this.add(this.props.drawings);
            some_var = next.paths.length - 1;
            this.setState({
                some_var: some_var,
                draft_point: {x: x, y: y},//seems like this x and y values 
            needs to replaced as well...
            });
         } else {
             next = this.props.drawings;
             this.setState({
                 some_var: undefined,
             });
         }
         const variable = next.paths[some_var];
         next_drawings = this.add_path(
             next, converted_point[0], converted_point[1], 
             converted_point[2]);
             this.props.on_drawings_changed(next_drawings);
     }).catch(some_method_called);
 };
```

The above method accepts `x` and `y` values, so basically it is called by another function like below. Here `x` and `y` are, say, 20 and 30 and when given to `this.props.convert_point` method in `add_point_at`, the output is say `[11.2, -13, 45]`, so basically `converted_point` given to the `then` method is `[11.2, -13, 45]`:

```
handle_click = (x, y) => {
    this.add_point_at(x,y);
}
```

This works fine. Now there is a situation where I have `x`, `y` and `z` values already and want to call the `add_point_at` method… So I divided the `add_point_at` method as below:

```
add_point_at = (x, y) => {
    this.props.convert_point([x, 
    y]).then(this.call_another_method).catch(some_method_called);

call_another_method = (converted_point) => {
    let next;
    let some_var = this.state.some_var;
    if (some_var === undefined) {
        this.method1();
        next = this.add(this.props.drawings);
        some_var = next.paths.length - 1;
        this.setState({
            some_var: some_var,
            draft_point: {x: x, y: y},// x and y values are unknown
        });
        console.log("last statement in if");
    } else {
        next = this.props.drawings;
        this.setState({
            some_var: undefined,
        });
    }
    console.log("first statement after else");
    const variable = next.paths[some_var];
    next_drawings = this.add_path(
        next, converted_point[0], converted_point[1], 
        converted_point[2]);
        this.props.on_drawings_changed(next_drawings);
};
```

So if I have `x`, `y` and `z` values already, I directly call:

```
this.call_another_method(converted_point);
```

If I have only `x` and `y` values, I call

```
this.add_point_at(x, y);
```

…so that this converts `x`, `y` to `x`, `y`, `z` values using the `this.props.convert_point` method.

But after dividing the method, it doesn't work. I don't see any console error. To debug, I tried to add console statements as seen in code above, but it is not logged to the console. Not sure why.

Could someone help me understand where the problem is?

EDIT: i realised that the problem is with the x and y values undefined in the splitted method...how can i refactor this method such that x and y values are replaced with something.